# changes on windows registry doesn’t take effect immediately

Tags: python, windows, qt, internet-explorer, pyqt

changes on windows registry doesn’t take effect immediately

I am trying to change IE’s proxy settings by the following 2 code snippets

to enable the proxy by this code

```
from winreg import *
with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" ,0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS) as key:
    SetValueEx(key,"ProxyServer",0, REG_SZ, "127.0.0.1:8087")
    SetValueEx(key,"ProxyEnable",0, REG_DWORD, 1)
    SetValueEx(key,"ProxyOverride",0, REG_SZ, "<local>")
FlushKey(key)
```

to disable the proxy by this code

```
from winreg import *
with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" ,0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS) as key:

    DeleteValue(key,"ProxyServer")
    SetValueEx(key,"ProxyEnable",0, REG_DWORD, 0)
    DeleteValue(key,"ProxyOverride")
    FlushKey(key)
```

but the changes on windows registry doesn’t take effect immediately,so is there some way to change the windows registry and let the changes  take effect immediately without restarting IE ?

BTW ,I use the code on winxp ,and I am going to embed the 2 code snippets in my PyQt application .

Answer (score 0):

Let's try like this: I hate too restarts , and fight against them , so , You could try to unload ieplore.dll , then reload it , but w/o crashing IE. Mentioned *.dll is a core of IE , and is really tricky , as for example , *.chm files load it w/o IE , and if URL is inside , it will open and load , and You wont see IE process running in task manager.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are after, entirely restarting seems unnecessary. As soon as a new Internet Explorer is opened, the settings are applied for the new Internet Explorer, and any other applications (such as Firefox).

If you're scripting it out, you may want to create a hidden window with an embedded Internet Explorer.

Again, depending on what you are after, there may be ready tools that do this. It settled my needs: I am now using [IE Proxy Toggle](http://download.cnet.com/IE-Proxy-Toggle/3000-2381_4-75863967.html).